# about the spanned divisor of a complex variety

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I have this definition:
let $\xi \in H^1(X,O^*)$ a cocycle. We say that $\xi$ is spanned if for every point $x$ in my variety $X$ there exist a section $s \in H^0(X,O(\xi))$ such that $s(x) \neq 0$.
If $\xi$ is spanned i know that the base locus of the complete linear system associated to $[D]=\xi$, named $|D|$ , is base point free. How can i see that $Bs|D|=\emptyset$ ?
I think that $\forall x\in X $ i have to found a divisor $ D^{'}$ such that $x\notin supp(D^{'})$ . How can i construct this $D^{'}$?

Comment: I think you're confused about a definition but I can't tell which one. What does base point free mean to you?

Comment: base point free means that the base locus is empty where the base locus is defined as $Bs|D|= \cap_{D\in |D|}supp(D)$ where $supp(D)$ is the support of the divisor $D$

Comment: You said you know the divisor is base point free, but you are asking why the base locus is empty.

Comment: On my book there is this remark about spanned divisor without a justification of it.

Comment: for $x\in X$, take $s\in H^0(X,O(\xi))$ with $s(x)\neq 0$ and let $D'=(s)_0$ be the divisor of zeroes of $s$.  This is linearly equivalent to $D$ and effective, and $x\notin supp(D')$